# How to set up Apache virtual host such as http://home/, http://office/, etc

Tags: apache, virtual, host

So rather than http://localhost, is it possible to set up multiple virtual hosts on the same local computer so I can access:

http://home/
http://office/
http://docs/

for different websites that are hosted at different document root directories in my computer?

Comment: If you are in a mood for games - edit the "hosts" file ( add 127.0.0.1 home, 127.0.0.1 docs ... etc). Then if you are using php based on $_SERVER[SERVER_NAME] load the scripts\sites. Good question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Install multiple virtual hosts](http://www.trailheadinteractive.com/creating_multiple_virtual_sites_a_single_apache_install_windows_xp)

Check this page for a useful information on what you want to know.