# Website in lan with virtual host?

Tags: apache, networking, xampp

I have a specefic problem, i have more websites on my localhost server (xammp), they has a virtul host, but i want to access this websites trough lan or wlan because so i can test it on mobile devices. If i call only ip on other device then i see xammp control panel, but i don't know how can i call websites in lan like: "site1.local, site2.local, site3.local", are here static ip's needed? On the router is **DHCP** enabled. I read few topics and this is all clear for me, the problem is only access on this sites trough network.

Read topics: 
[How to set up Apache virtual host such as http://home/, http://office/, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385969/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-host-such-as-http-home-http-office-etc)
[Accessing localhost (xampp) from another computer over LAN network - how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to)
[How to set up Apache virtual host such as http://home/, http://office/, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385969/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-host-such-as-http-home-http-office-etc)
[Apache: see named virtual hosts from LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922082/apache-see-named-virtual-hosts-from-lan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find your IP of your server machine. If it uses windows, press start then type into the search bar cmd. Then when a command promt comes up type in ipconfig and hit enter. Look for "IPv4-address" and to the right of that is your local IP of your computer.

Then you can use a computer on your wireless LAN or a wired connection. Simply type in the IP of your computers local IP with XAMP, and you are good to go!

Hope this helped
-Kad

Comment: Keep in mind when you use DHCP your local IP of your server will change eventually. Then you will have to find the IP again, unless you make it a static one.

Answer (score 0):

I do this on work for testing. We have a XAMPP localhost server. My projects are in the htdocs folder. like this: c:\xampp\htdocs\niceproject
The IP for reqesting xampp is something like this: 192.168.10.104.

Now for calling the Websites just do this:  192.168.10.104/niceproject

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To access multiple sites (virtual hosts) served from one machine (say *lanwww* running **apache**) on mobile devices the usage of **ServerName** (say *site1*, **ServerAlias** *site1.lanwww*) fails - the DHCP on the router won't map subhosts (*site1.lanwww*). I found that using different ports for the subsites works nicely though - remember to add appropriate **Listen** statements to the **ports.conf**. The configuration of other webservers is left as an exercise to the reader.